# Eclipse with Remote Systems Using PDT Wont Save

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-pdt, eclipse-rse

As the title outlined I'm using Eclipse with PDT to work on a remote server. Remote Services will let me create a file and delete it, however it will not allow me to update the remote file. Any ideas why?

Eclipse Version: 3.7.2,

Comment: After much frustration I just deleted the connection in remote systems and added it again. it worked. LOL

Comment: lol I am on ubuntu, how did you do this? It didn't work for me :(